# summation of 0.5n to n

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Is there a way to write the following series as some sort of a formula? I know one exists for the sum of integers but this is a bit different:

```
(n-1)+(n-2)+ ... + 0.5n
```

or

```
0.5n + (0.5n + 1) + (0.5n + 2) + ... + (n - 1)
```

i'm assuming these are the same thing

Comment: ... is $n$ supposed to be even? Otherwise I don't understand the pattern you're getting at.

Comment: 1+2+...+n = 0.5n(n+1), what i need is the same summation starting at 0.5n and ending with n-1

Comment: They aren't the same thing. The latter is $n$ bigger than the former.

Comment: @Supernatrual: I'm sorry, I don't see how that helps. Why don't you write out the **full** series you mean for a specific $n$; let's say $n=5$.

Comment: Maybe it would help you to write $m = 0.5n$, and then express what you want with $m$ instead of $n$. Substitute again when you're done.

Comment: hm it is not mentioned if n is supposed to be even but let's assume it is

Comment: It looks like $n$ must be even, and if $n = 10$, then the series is $9 + 8 + 7 + 6 + 5$.

Comment: @Yoni Rozenshein that is brilliant, I wish I could rate your answer somehow, totally worked the formula worked out as 0.25n(3n/2-1)

Comment: One other thing to note - mathetmaticians don't like to write $0.5$ when they mean exactly $\frac{1}{2}$. Decimals have a strong hint that they are approximations rather than exact values, and fractions are clearer. @Supernatural

Comment: thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the comments, the user Supernatural has indicated that we are now to assume that $n$ is even.

If $n=2m$ for an integer $m$, then
$$\begin{align*}(0.5 n)+(0.5n+1)+\cdots+(0.5n+0.5n)&=(m)+(m+1)+\cdots+(m+m)\\\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^{m}(m+j)\\\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^mm+\sum_{j=0}^mj\\\\
&=m(m+1)+\frac{m(m+1)}{2}\\\\
&=\frac{3m^2+3m}{2}\\\\
&=\frac{3n^2+6n}{8}
\end{align*}$$

In contrast,
$$\begin{align*}(n-1)+(n-2)+\cdots+(0.5n)&=(2m-1)+(2m-2)+\cdots+(m)\\\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^{m}(2m-j)\\\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^m2m-\sum_{j=1}^mj\\\\
&=2m^2-\frac{m(m+1)}{2}\\\\
&=\frac{3m^2-m}{2}\\\\
&=\frac{3n^2-2n}{8}
\end{align*}$$

Comment: If n = 6 we are summing up 3, 4 and 5 = 12. your solution gives a different answer

Comment: @Supernatural You wrote to $n-1$ in one place, and to $0.5n +0.5n$ in the other.  So Zev solved the latter problem, 3+4+5+6

Comment: sorry my mistake!

Comment: thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that $n$ is even, then the first formula sums the first $n-1$ positive integers, then subtracts the sum of the first $\frac n2-1$. That is, $$\frac{(n-1)n}2-\cfrac{\left(\frac n2-1\right)\cdot\frac n2}2=\frac{(n-1)n}2-\frac{(n-2)n}8=\frac{(3n-2)n}8.$$ The second formula is $n$ more than this.

Comment: If n = 6 we are summing up 3, 4 and 5 = 12. your solution gives 9 as an answer

Comment: @Supernatural: I made an arithmetic error, but I noticed and fixed it.

Comment: thank you very much for the help!!